# Creating All Possible Combinations in a Table Using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a table with four variables and i want the table a table with combination of all values. Showing a table with only 2 columns as an example.

```
NAME    AMOUNT  COUNT
RAJ 90  1
RAVI    20  4
JOHN    30  5
JOSEPH  40  3
```

The following output is to show the values only for raj and the output should be for all names.

```
NAME    AMOUNT  COUNT
RAJ 90  1
RAJ 90  4
RAJ 90  5
RAJ 90  3
RAJ 20  1
RAJ 20  4
RAJ 20  5
RAJ 20  3
RAJ 30  1
RAJ 30  4
RAJ 30  5
RAJ 30  3
RAJ 40  1
RAJ 40  4
RAJ 40  5
RAJ 40  3
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of useful options in SAS to do this; both create a table with all possible combinations of variables, and then you can just drop the summary data that you don't need.  Given your initial dataset:

```
data have;
input NAME $ AMOUNT  COUNT;
datalines;
RAJ 90  1
RAVI    20  4
JOHN    30  5
JOSEPH  40  3
;;;;
run;
```

There is `PROC FREQ` with `SPARSE`.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
tables name*amount*count/sparse out=want(drop=percent);
run;
```

There is also PROC TABULATE.

```
proc tabulate data=have out=want(keep=name amount count);
class name amount count;
tables name*amount,count /printmiss;
run;
```

This has the advantage of not conflicting with the name for the COUNT variable.

Comment: Thank you very much Joe. The programs provided have solved my problem. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE tbl_out AS
SELECT a.name AS name 
       ,b.amount AS amount
       ,c.count AS count
FROM tbl_in AS a, tbl_in AS b, tbl_in AS c
;
QUIT;
```

This performs a double self-join and should have the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you very much Justin. Tested the program and it gave me the desired results. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on @JustinJDavies's answer, using an explicit `CROSS JOIN` clause:

```
data have;
  input NAME $ AMOUNT  COUNT;
  datalines;
RAJ     90  1
RAVI    20  4
JOHN    30  5
JOSEPH  40  3
run;

PROC SQL;
  create table combs as
    select * 
      from have(keep=NAME)
        cross join have(keep=AMOUNT)
        cross join have(keep=COUNT)
      order by name, amount, count;
QUIT;
```

Results:

```
NAME AMOUNT COUNT 
JOHN 20     1 
JOHN 20     3 
JOHN 20     4 
JOHN 20     5 
JOHN 30     1 
JOHN 30     3 
JOHN 30     4 
JOHN 30     5 
...
```