# Combine two datasets without a common variable in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, dataset

Hi wanted to know how to combine the following example:

Data1

```
Groups
ABC 
FVC
HTR
```

Data2

```
Riders
H2
H3
```

Final or wanted table

```
Groups  RIDERS
ABC       H2
ABC       H3
FVC       H2
FVC       H3
HTR       H2
HTR       H3
```

Comment: can't seem to better visualize the wanted results but I basically want each Groups (ABC,FVC, etc ) to have the RIDERS  in DATA2 added to each group.

Comment: I fixed it for you this time, please review how to do this yourself. This is a duplicate question though and I'll mark it as such in a few minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating All Possible Combinations in a Table Using SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646976/creating-all-possible-combinations-in-a-table-using-sas)

Comment: Link to documentation reference: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n082a03omu3i21n1k889zfklh4ps.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls [the cartesian product](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/270.html).

You can do it without `cross join` :

```
proc sql;
    select d1.groups, d2.riders
    from data1 d1,
         data2 d2;
quit;
```

Comment: I think it faster then `cross join`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `cross join`.  Using `proc sql`, this would be:

```
proc sql;
    select d1.groups, d2.riders
    from data1 d1 cross join
         data2 d2
    order by d1.groups d2.riders;
quit;
```